# Your search yielded no results in Drupal 7.12. I have index 100%. In my local it is working but on the staging server it is not working

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Your search yielded no results in Drupal 7.12. I have index 100%. In my local it is working but on the staging server it is not working.
    **Check if your spelling is correct.
    Remove quotes around phrases to search for each word individually. bike shed will often show more results than "bike shed".
    Consider loosening your query with OR. bike OR shed will often show more results than bike shed.**

Comment: I got the solution. It is a unicode issue. I have added the patch....

Answer (score 0):

In your search module locate "x{d800}", and replace it with "x{e000}". 
This issue has been fixed in the latest version of Drupal.